# Is $\mathcal{C}([0,1])$ homeomorphic to a Hilbert space?

Tags: general-topology, analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $\mathcal{C}([0,1])$ the Banach space of continuous functions from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb{C}$. The norm on $\mathcal{C}([0,1])$ is $f \mapsto \| f\|_{\infty}= \sup_{x \in [0,1]} |f(x)|$.

Is it possible that there is an homeomorphism $\phi$ from $\mathcal{C}([0,1])$ onto $H$, a Hilbert space ?

I have shown it's not possible if $\phi$ is supposed to be linear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is Anderson-Kadec Theorem: Each separable Frechet (=locally convex complete linear metric) space is homeomorphic to a Hilbert space.

Also there is a paper by Taras Banakh and Igor Zarichnyy, [Topological groups and convex sets homeomorphic to non-separable Hilbert spaces](http://prima.lnu.edu.ua/faculty/mechmat/Departments/Topology/banpap/hilbert.pdf), Central European J. of Math. 6:1 (2008), 77–86.